# Android worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I would like to make a thread in android that runs in the back. The thread keeps checking the time with a while loop and if it matches it does something. This all works great. But the app is not responsive, as if i'm not running a thread at all. The while still blocks everything. I don't understand why.

code of the thread:

```
public class AlarmThread implements Runnable {

LocalTime beginTime;
LocalTime endTime;

public AlarmThread(LocalTime beginTime, LocalTime endTime) {
    this.beginTime = beginTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

@Override
public void run() {
     while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentTime = java.time.LocalTime.now();
        if(currentTime.isAfter(beginTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime)){
            sendNotification();
         }
      }
}
```

the activity:

```
public void onButtonClickerDatepicker(View v) throws IOException {
    LocalTime beginTime = java.time.LocalTime.of(binding.simpleTimePicker.getHour(), binding.simpleTimePicker.getMinute());
    LocalTime endTime = java.time.LocalTime.of(binding.simpleTimePicker2.getHour(), binding.simpleTimePicker2.getMinute());
    alarmThread = new AlarmThread(beginTime, endTime);
    alarmThread.run();

}
```

Comment: Does this has to be on UI thread ? What I mean was, can this task be done in background ?

Comment: the ui does not need an update. So yes, it can be done in the background

Comment: Then you should give WorkManager a try. More on WorkManager here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Thread.start()` to start a thread otherthan `Thread.run()`.
And what's more your AlarmThread is not a Thread but a Runnable. So you can start it by code below:

```
private Thread workerThread = new Thread(new AlarmThread(start, end))
...
...
workerThread.start()
```

I recommend you use [HandlerThread](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0mkYSjldeA) for flexibility

Comment: I think it's important to repeat that `AlarmThread` *does not* extend `Thread` and therefore should be renamed to avoid confusion like this, call it `AlarmRunnable` or something like this.